# Using Chinese Characters In Firefox On RHEL 6.5

Tags: firefox, rhel-6, chinese

**Firefox 38.2.1**

**RHEL 6.5 ( Redhat Enterprise Linux )**

I was excited to learn that I could type Chinese characters and other foreign languages in Gmail just by adjusting some preferences in my Gmail account.

I *thought* it was OS independent.

Then I got to work, set the same preferences, and only got little blank squares instead of Chinese characters.

Can I install an extension into Firefox to fix this, or do I need to have language packs installed at the OS/Linux level?

Comment: Can you type Chinese characters in other applications allowing text input? Unless it is only different in gmail, it seems to be a system level issue (meaning language packs need to be installed).

Comment: Yes, it is system wide.  I was hoping gmail was independent as it is difficult to get software installed at work.